# how to show Time in 12 hours format in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I am developing an app whenever a user add some details the record get stored in database as created date time in 24 hour format. But for display purpose i am showing the time in 12 hour format. i.e i have used "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a" format to display the time and it show properly on my screen, but the problem is whenever user change the date/time format from 12 hour to 24 hour format in setting. My app start to show the time in 24 hour format. Can anyone plz help me that even though the user change the setting to 24 hour format in setting. Time format should not change from 12 to 24 hour.

Comment: If the user changes the time format from 12 to 24 hour, that's because he/she likes it that way.  You should respect the user's choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should allow the user to choose how they want to display it.

With your code, you should be able to do this:

```
dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLocale *twelveHourLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];
dateFormat.locale = twelveHourLocale;
CreatedDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[serviceAntInstance.arr_CreatedDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
createdDateConvert = [dateFormat stringFromDate:CreatedDate];
```

Comment: here is the code whether i convert the datetime format /* to convert date into another format */
        dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        CreatedDate        =  [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[serviceAntInstance.arr_CreatedDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
        createdDateConvert = [dateFormat stringFromDate:CreatedDate];

Comment: Time format is specified for user locale. It is preferred settings, and your application should present date information in such a way, that it must be convenient to user to perceive it. So, generally, you should NOT change format to 12-h.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to force a locale that uses 12 hour format. This is from Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1480.html

Answer (score 2):

Please check out this :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatterTemp = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatterTemp setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatterTemp setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[formatterTemp setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSRange amRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatterTemp AMSymbol]];
NSRange pmRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatterTemp PMSymbol]];
BOOL is24h = (amRange.location == NSNotFound && pmRange.location == NSNotFound);
[formatterTemp release];
NSLog(@"%@\n",(is24h ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about taking advantage of existing locales?

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setLocale: locale];
[formatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];

[formatter release];
[locale release];
```